# Paraphrase that sentence

Tags: paraphrasing

Could you please help me to paraphrase the following sentence:

> The school does contribute to the socialization process through outright indoctrination implicit in the content of school activities

I only replaced *through*  by *via*. I can't make it shorter and keeping the essential meaning

Comment: Paraphrase to what end? Shorter? More readable?

Comment: _The outright indoctrination, implicit in the school activities, contributes to the socialization process_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence

> The school does contribute to the socialization process through
>   outright indoctrination implicit in the content of school activities.

could be rephrased as

> The school helps students to integrate in society by encouraging them
>   to take part in school activities.

I have three observations on the original sentence.

> The school does contribute . . .

suggests the school is defensive, after being challenged about its worth, and

> . . . through outright indoctrination . . .

suggests that ex-curricular activities are compulsory.

The third observation is that forced measures are often counter-productive, and I wonder how much the school really does try to integrate students into society, and not alienate them. That is perhaps why the statement was issued. Sadly, the school's representative seems to be hiding behind hubris by writing such a sentence.